# Microsoft Access: Filter out Movies with Faults, and movies that are already rented

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Database for a Movie Business which has a DVD table (DVDID, Title, Faults) and a Rental table (RentalID, MemberID, DVDID, DateRented, DateReturned).

I want to make a query that will determine what Movies are available for hire. To do this, it needs to exclude DVDs with faults in the DVD table, and DVDs that haven't been returned in the Rental table.

DVDs are known to have a fault when there is content in the 'Fault' column in the DVD table. If the field is empty, the DVD has no fault. DVDs are known to be returned when there is content in the 'DateReturned' field of the Rental Table.

So far, I've managed to exclude DVDs with faults and exclude DVDs in the Rental table, but this needs to be improved so it only excludes DVDs in the Rental table if the DateReturned field is Null.

```
SELECT DVD.DVDID, DVD.Title, DVD.Rating, DVD.Genre, DVD.Released, DVD.RentalPeriod, DVD.Distributor, DVD.Faults
FROM DVD
WHERE (((DVD.Faults) Is Null) AND ((Exists (SELECT 1 FROM Rental WHERE Rental.DVDID = DVD.DVDID))=False));
```

Anyone have any ideas how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this shows you the DVDs which have been rented but not yet returned ...

```sql
SELECT DVDID
FROM Rental
WHERE DateReturned Is Null;
```

Use that as a subquery and `LEFT JOIN` your `DVD` table to it.

```sql
SELECT
    DVD.DVDID,
    DVD.Title,
    DVD.Rating,
    DVD.Genre,
    DVD.Released,
    DVD.RentalPeriod,
    DVD.Distributor,
    DVD.Faults
FROM
    DVD
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DVDID
            FROM Rental
            WHERE DateReturned Is Null
        ) AS sub
        ON DVD.DVID = sub.DVID
WHERE
        DVD.Faults Is Null
    AND sub.DVID Is Null;
```

In the `WHERE` clause,  `DVD.Faults Is Null` excludes those with faults, and `sub.DVID Is Null` excludes those which have been rented and not returned.